# Closed form of partition function in $0+0$-dimenional $\phi^4$ theory

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, path-integral, partition-function

**The problem:**

In one of McGreevy's excellent exercises in QFT, we are given the $0+0$ dimensional partition function
$$Z=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}dq\ e^{-S(q)}\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (1)$$,
where
$$S(q)=\frac{1}{2}m^2q^2+gq^4$$
Through $$\int dq \dfrac{\partial}{\partial q}\left( q\ e^{-S(q)}\right)=0\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  (2)$$
we are directed to reach the Schwinger-Dyson equation for $Z$ and show that they lead to an equation whose solution is of the form $$\mathcal{Z}(1/y)=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{y}}e^{-a/y}K_\nu(y)$$
where $a, \nu$ are to be determined, $K_\nu$ is a modified Bessel of the second kind and $\mathcal{Z}$ is defined through $Z=\frac{1}{\sqrt{m^2}}\mathcal{Z}(g/m^4)$. I'm guessing McGreevy is purposefully vague about what $y$ is but I'm guessing it's a multiple of $g/m^4$.

---

**Attempt at a solution:**

$\mathcal{Z}$ is easy to find with a change of integration variable. Doing so, I could not proceed further, so I will outline my attempt at the solution. I re-wrote
$$Z=g^{-1/4}\int dq e^{-m^2/(2\sqrt{g})q^2-q^4}=\sqrt{\xi}\int dq e^{-S'}$$
where I have defined $\xi=\frac{m^2}{\sqrt{g}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{g}}$ and I have taken $m=1$ for simplicity.  Also, $S'=\frac{m^2}{2\sqrt{g}}q^2+q^4$. Using equation (2) for $S'$, I find:
$$\int dq e^{-S'}=\int dq (\xi q^2+4q^4)e^{-S'}=-2(\xi \frac{\partial}{\partial \xi}-8\frac{\partial^2}{\partial \xi^2})\int dq e^{-(\xi q^2/2+q^4)}\ \ \ \ \ \ (3)$$
I then write on both the LHS and RHS $\int dq e^{-S'}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\xi}}Z$ and find (after taking the appropriate derivatives)
$$8 \frac{\partial^2 Z}{\partial \xi^2}-\left( 1+\frac{8}{\xi} \right)\frac{\partial Z}{\partial \xi} +\frac{6}{\xi^2}Z=0\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (4)$$
Now, if this is correct, I can just plug in the ansatz $Z\propto\xi^a e^{b\xi^2} f(\xi)$ (which is indeed the correct ansatz, as it agrees with the solution found in eq.(10) of http://cds.cern.ch/record/401392/files/9909175.pdf) and then find $a, b$ in order for $f(\xi)$ to satisfy the modified Bessel equation.

---

**Questions:**

(1) The most important one is whether equation (4) is correct; I think it might be the essence of the exercise. The most crucial step that must be correct is the trick that leads to the last equality in equation (3).

(2) Even if this is a correct way to solve the exercise, when I do it like McGreevy suggests, I first need to write
$$Z=\frac{1}{\sqrt{m^2}}\int dq e^{-(q^2/2+gq^4/m^4)}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{m^2}}\int dq e^{-(q^2/2+q^4/\xi^2)}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{m^2}}\int dq e^{-S''}$$
My only problem with this is that when I use equation (2), I find something analogous to the first equality of equation (3), but I then don't know how to implement the trick I used to get the RHS in equation (3). In particular:
$$\int dq e^{-S''}=\int dq \left( q^2+4q^4/\xi^2  \right) e^{=S''}=\ ?$$

---

Any help on any of my questions is very appreciated.

Comment: For anybody who might be interested, McGreevy shares a lot of excellent material (notes, problem sets, partial solutions) on his website:
https://mcgreevy.physics.ucsd.edu/

P.S. The above problem is from a problem set of a Quantum Field Theory C course from past years. It was accessible up to some months ago.

Comment: This seems to be from [problem set 2](https://mcgreevy.physics.ucsd.edu/s15/215C-pset02.pdf) from Spring 2015, if anyone else is trying to find where this problem comes from...

Comment: @AlexNelson I thought it wasn't accessible anymore. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I really enjoyed this calculation.

As you have already shown
$$
Z(m,g) = \frac{1}{g^{1/4}} f \left( \frac{m^2}{2\sqrt{g}} \right) , \qquad f(x) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty dq e^{-q^4 - x q^2} 
$$
We immediately note
$$
f'(x) = - \int_{-\infty}^\infty dq e^{-q^4 - x q^2} q^2 = - \langle q^2 \rangle , \qquad f''(x) =  \int_{-\infty}^\infty dq e^{-q^4 - x q^2} q^4 =  \langle q^4 \rangle 
$$
Next, we use
\begin{align}
0 &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty dq \frac{\partial}{\partial q} \left( q e^{-q^4 - x q^2}  \right) \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty dq   e^{-q^4 - x q^2} [ 1 - 4 q^4 - 2 x q^2 ] \\
&= f(x) - 4 f''(x) + 2 x f'(x)
\end{align}
We can simply solve this differential equation as
$$
f(x) = c_1 H_{-1/2} (x/2) + c_2 e^{x^2/8} \,_0 F_1\left( \frac{3}{4} , \frac{x^4}{256}\right)
$$
The constants can be fixed by evaluating
$$
Z(m,0) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty dq e^{-\frac{1}{2} m^2 q^2 } = \frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{m} .
$$
Therefore
$$
\lim_{g \to 0} \frac{1}{g^{1/4}} f \left( \frac{m^2}{2\sqrt{g}} \right) = \frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{m} \quad \implies \quad \lim_{x \to \infty}  \sqrt{x} f(x) =  \sqrt{\pi} 
$$
$\,_0 F_1$ falls off as a power law at large $x$ so we must have $c_2 = 0$. On the other hand $H_{-1/2} (x/2) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} + O(x^{-5/2})$ so we set $c_1 = \sqrt{\pi}$. Putting all of this together, we find
$$
Z(m,g) = \frac{1}{g^{1/4}} f \left( \frac{m^2}{2\sqrt{g}} \right)  = \int dq e^{-\frac{1}{2} m^2 q^2 - g q^4 } = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{ g^{1/4}} H_{-1/2} \left( \frac{m^2}{4\sqrt{g}} \right) .
$$
Equivalently,
$$
Z(m,g) = \frac{m}{\sqrt{8g}} e^{ m^4 / (32 g) } K_{\frac{1}{4}} \left( \frac{m^4}{32g} \right) .
$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the calculation was indeed a joy! From what I can see, your equation for $f(x)$ matches my equation (3) (for $x=\xi/2$), but our approach after that is different. I guess I wanted to use as few info about special functions as possible.
I'm guessing that if you inserted $f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2x}}Z$ in your differential equation for $f(x)$, you could insert the ansatz $Z=c\ x^a e^{bx^2}g(cx)$ for some function $g$ (as I proposed in my question) to show that the differential equation for $g$ is the modified Bessel equation (cont.)

Comment: (cont) for appropriate $a,b, c$ (to be determined by the terms in front of $g'', g', g$). Do you see anything wrong with this attempt? Note that we can also specify that $g=K_\nu$ in the ansatz by examining the asymptotic behaviour of $Z$ and $K_\nu$ in the limit $x\rightarrow \infty$, similarly to what you did.

Comment: EDIT: it should be $g(c x^2)$ from asymptotic analysis